# how to import directory/package in flutter

Tags: flutter, import, package

I have the following imports

```
import 'package:redacted/Pages/BasePage.dart' as Pages;
import 'package:redacted/Pages/FreeText.dart' as Pages;
import 'package:redacted/Pages/Generic.dart' as Pages;
import 'package:redacted/Pages/Numeric.dart' as Pages;
import 'package:redacted/Pages/Identity.dart' as Pages;
```

I would like to do something like this

`import 'package:redacted/Pages' as Pages;`

So i can do the following in code : `Pages.Generic`, or `Pages.Numeric`

If the 5 why's interest you, here's at least one. I'm using other classes of the same name, but different content.

```
import 'package:redacted/Content/BaseContent.dart' as Content;
import 'package:redacted/Content/FreeText.dart' as Content;
import 'package:redacted/Content/Generic.dart' as Content;
import 'package:redacted/Content/Numeric.dart' as Content;
import 'package:redacted/Content/Identity.dart' as Content;
```

Content is the content of the page, page is the UI of the page. In the file in question I need both imports, this is where I'll do the content-page matching. So I need to be able to differentiate.

Ideally I'd just type `Content.FreeText` or `Pages.FreeText` and I would be good to go, but right now I need to add the `as Pages`  and  `as Content` on every import, on top of having to import everything manually.

Is there something like the following that is possible ?

```
import 'package:redacted/Pages' as Pages;
import 'package:redacted/Content' as Content;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could create a "index" file that exports all the classes you want to bundle.

For example `redacted/Content/screens.dart`:

```dart
export 'BaseContent.dart';
export 'FreeText.dart';
export 'Generic.dart';
export 'Numeric.dart';
export 'Identity.dart';
```

Once you have that, you can import it via:

```dart
import 'package:redacted/Content/screens.dart' as Screens;
```

It's quite similar to how you would [create a Dart library package](https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/create-library-packages).

Comment: Yep, it works exactly like I want it to. Great answer, thanks a lot :)